# how to display a php function on my html that run well on ajax side

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to display the result of a php function that I call in AJAX into a div 'TARGET'. I can't understand what I am doing wrong....

MY HTML

```
<div id="TARGET"></div>
```

MY AJAX

```
$(document).on('click', '.actualiser_btn', function(){
        var id_contenu = $(this).attr("id");
        $.ajax({
            url:"/ajax-script.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{id_contenu:id_contenu},
            dataType:"json",
            success:function(data)
            {       
                $('#TARGET').html(<?php $return ?>);                
            }
        })
    });
```

MY AJAX SCRIPT

```
...
$return =  wysiwyg( $_POST['id_contenu'],'basique') ;
echo $return ;
?>
```

When I click on the script in my network debugger I exactly see the script that I want so I conclude my function works well... What Am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to understand the difference between server-side code and client-side code. You can't do that (view source to see why).  Instead, use the response.

Comment: What you receive on AJAX side is `data` not `$return`

Comment: Further to what @SLaks mentioned, the response to the AJAX request is held in the JS `data` variable (on the client side), not in the `$response` PHP variable (which is on the server side)

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `data` to update the html like `$('#TARGET').html(data.key);`

```
$(document).on('click', '.actualiser_btn', function(){
    var id_contenu = $(this).attr("id");
    $.ajax({
        url:"/ajax-script.php",
        method:"POST",
        data:{id_contenu:id_contenu},
        dataType:"json",
        success:function(data)
        {       
            $('#TARGET').html(data.key);  /*Since data is json, you might want to access the right key/value to set as html*/              
        }
    })
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

**success function**

> Type: Function( Anything data, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR ) A
>   function to be called if the request succeeds. The function gets
>   passed three arguments: The data returned from the server, formatted
>   according to the dataType parameter or the dataFilter callback
>   function, if specified; a string describing the status; and the jqXHR
>   (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object. As of jQuery 1.5, the
>   success setting can accept an array of functions. Each function will
>   be called in turn. This is an Ajax Event.

The first parameter of the success function is the data received from the backend.

Comment: thank you very much.. But I still have my return problem. the generated script displays well on my network debugger but impossible to display it on my page.. even with the method you've sent. But thanks, that's axis for my research

Comment: One thing I would like to point out, Since you are using `dataType:"json"`, you should return or echo a valid json format.

Comment: If your `$return` is array, yes. If not you can `echo json_encode( array( "key" => $return ) );`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.. On my debugger I have {"key":null}

Comment: Great! You are on the right track. Your `$return` variable is `null`

Comment: $('#TARGET').html(data.key); still doesn't work . I'm so close when I click on my ajax php script everything looks so fine... wtf

Comment: What does console returns? Can you try `echo json_encode( array( "key" => "TEST DATA" ) );`

Comment: I get "{"key":"TEST DATA"}" on debugger  and nothing on html side

Comment: So are you able to see "TEST DATA" on `$('#TARGET')`?

Comment: Do you still have `dataType:"json",` on your reuest?

Comment: Is there anything else rendered with `{"key":"TEST DATA"}`? Can you provide the console screenshot?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/YTKJT I get something like that. I've just noticed that if I remove my function, TEST DATA appears

Comment: Maybe your function is throwing errors and that will make the returned data invalid json firmat. The data  returned should be a valid json format.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `$('#TARGET').html(<?php $return ?>);` with `$('#TARGET').html( data );`
as shown below.

Also note that the `dataType` option in the ajax request expects a JSON response therefore, ensure that your response is in a JSON format. Alternatively, remove the option.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.actualiser_btn', function(){
        var id_contenu = $(this).attr("id");
        $.ajax({
            url:"/ajax-script.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{id_contenu:id_contenu},
            dataType:"json",
            success:function(data, status){
                $('#TARGET').html( data );
            }
        });
    });
```